# How can I send an data using AJAX in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want so send an ajax request in my page but I don't know how.
Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': {!! json_encode(csrf_token()) !!},
            }
        });

        $('.del_btn').on('click', function(){

            var id = $(this).data('id');

            $.ajax({
                url: "posts/something",
                type: 'post',
                dateType: 'json',
                data: {name: 'rochelle'},
                beforeSend: function() { console.log('loading'); },
                success: function(d) {
                    console.log(d.test);
                },
                error: function() { alert('error'); }
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

Then I registered the route:

```
Route::get('posts/something', 'PostsController@something');
```

In my controller I have this:

```
    public function something() {

        $test = $request->input('name');

        return Response::json($test);

    }
```

I got this error in my dev console tab:

```
405 Method Not Allowed
```

Can you help me with this? I am new in laravel.

Comment: Tell us please, where you stop ? What is wrong ? Do you get an error, or it just dont work. Be more specific please.

Comment: route is get but you are trying to post

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius, ok sorry for the post. I will update.

Comment: @Jerielle isn't this seems problematic `{!! json_encode(csrf_token()) !!}` although your issue seems to be get/post.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing a post, but the laravel route is set to expect a get.

Change:

`Route::get('posts/something', 'PostsController@something');`

to:

`Route::post('posts/something', 'PostsController@something');`